# Julia git error

Tags: git, julia

Some months ago I was using Julia and recently I wanted to pick it up again. I wanted a fresh version so I deleted my previous version and all packages I had.

Now, after installing the new version *(0.6.2)*, I cannot use any Pkg. command : I will get the following error after using `init`, `add` or `update`

> ERROR : GitError(Code:ECERTIFICATE, Class:OS, user cancelled certificate check :)

I have tried reinstalling to no avail.

I am on Windows; I have seen many related problems answered by git commands but I have no idea on how to use them because they all seem to be destined to Linux users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please give us some more info? Which version of Windows are you using (Win 10?)? (32 or 64 bits?), which version of Julia are you trying to install? Which version of Julia you had working before? I can try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Windows 7 64 bits. I had Julia 0.5.0, I'm trying to install Julia 0.6.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this answer at JuliaLang Discourse by avik:

- https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pkg-update-error-base-libgit2-test-fails/9272/11

This is an issue which is solved by:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in

Please make sure to follow those instructions, you could also ask for help at the Gitter channel if you get stuck:

- https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am trying that right now and will accept your answer if it works

Comment: @Junkyards be sure to check out the **easy fix** in the link! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just run the `easy fix` tool in the following link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in

No need to update the protocol or anything I believe. Just run this easy fix.