# Installation of Julia on Windows7 64 bit

Tags: installation, julia, juno-ide

This might be a either silly or simple question for anyone else, but I'm in serious trouble with this, I'm very very new to Julia, honestly, this is my first time to Julia.

I want to learn Julia some more by myself because I've heard that Julia is much faster than R. I've experienced R for couple of years. but this blocked me.

anyway, I just installed Julia on my laptop (Windows7 64-bit) today and once I installed it, I had faced the error messages as below.

[The error message I had faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcszv.png)

and after the messages, console didn't work at all.
I don't know why such a error has occurred all I did were just download the installation file and click next couple of times. How could I shoot this trouble away?

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: I don't think this is a julia problem. It sounds like your SSL socket to github is failing. Can you navigate to [the github page](https://github.com/) with your web browser? Is your system clock set to something very different to current time? Are you on a work computer than might have various walls/blocks up to unknown web sites?

Comment: To the downvoter: the OP is a rep 1 user. I think it would be much more helpful to explain what is wrong with the question in the comments, rather than just spamming the downvote button.

Comment: Thank you for your helps, Collin. I will navigate github page for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia git error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950748/julia-git-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite tricky problem. It seems that Windows library which julia uses does not support the right version of TLS (an encryption standard).

Can you run the "Easy fix" tool from the Microsoft support page?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in

See also this discussion:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pkg-update-error-base-libgit2-test-fails/9272/11

Comment: thank you for your helps. I'll try your "easy-fix" solution.